# Spring Webflux - WebClient over TLSv1.2

Tags: java, spring

Small question regarding the Spring Webflux WebClient, and more particularly how to configure one to use TLSv1.2 to send outbound request.

My app is a Spring Webflux 2.4.2, where HTTP/2, SSL, mTLS and TLSv1.3 are enabled.

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
server.http2.enabled=true
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.key-password=
server.ssl.key-store-password=
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=/keystore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=
server.ssl.trust-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store=/truststore.p12
```

Note it is TLSv1.3, not TLSv1,2 on the setting.

When I create an instance of WebClient:

```
getWebClient().mutate().baseUrl("https://some-server.com").build().post().uri("/some/route").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

 @Bean
    @Primary
    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        return WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getSslContextBuilder())))).build();
    }


    public SslContextBuilder getSslContextBuilder() {
        try {
            final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)) {
                final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                keyStore.load(file, keyStorePassPhrase.toCharArray());
                keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassPhrase.toCharArray());
            }

            final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            try (InputStream trustStoreFile = new FileInputStream(trustStorePath)) {
                final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
                trustStore.load(trustStoreFile, trustStorePassPhrase.toCharArray());
                trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            }

            final ApplicationProtocolConfig applicationProtocolConfig = new ApplicationProtocolConfig(ApplicationProtocolConfig.Protocol.ALPN, ApplicationProtocolConfig.SelectorFailureBehavior.NO_ADVERTISE, ApplicationProtocolConfig.SelectedListenerFailureBehavior.ACCEPT, ApplicationProtocolNames.HTTP_2, ApplicationProtocolNames.HTTP_1_1);
            return SslContextBuilder.forClient().applicationProtocolConfig(applicationProtocolConfig).keyManager(keyManagerFactory).trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);
        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And use it to send a request to a TLSv1.3 enabled server, it is working fine, very happy.

However, some of the servers I need to interact with either have an old/different JDK version, or TLSv1.2 enabled (I am not owning those third party APIs).

Because I am getting:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
```

After research here in SO, I found out I can configure such.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }
```

And surprisingly, the issue is fixed (not knowing why).

My question is: instead of setting a system property, may I simply achieve the same with the WebClient on a code level please?

Thank you

Comment: The problematic servers are not TLS1.2, but 1.3 using client auth with status aka stapling (not in Java); this was a bug in Java fixed in 15 14.0.2 13.0.3 11.0.7 8u261 up and does not affect 1.2 which is why forcing the client to use 1.2 avoids the problem. It should be possible to do that in your SSLContext, but I'm not a springer so I can't answer that part.

Comment: But this is very good insight already, learned a lot. Thanks. Hopefully someone can drop by and help on the SSLContext part 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");` is the solution